# Facebook Graph API batch with multiple Apps

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, batch-file, sdk

Is it possible to create one batch request that gets/posts for multiple apps?

I'll give an example.

---

I have app1 with permissions for user1, user2, user3.
I have app2 with permissions for user4, user5

I need to post on the walls of all of these users, with one batch call.

---

I guess it would be possible if I could set appId and secret separately for each command in batch request. I am using PHP SDK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each app obviously has it's own App ID and Secret etc... So with each one you would need to make a request. With PHP you could do this in the same script providing you already have their access tokens, but I'm almost certain you would have to make more than one call for more than one app.

Comment: Unfortunately, that was my guess too... Thanks for confirming.